# Select2 upon click(not selected), show loading spinner javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Ok my code is quite simple. I am using sample data but in my real code, upon clicking the select2 dropdown, the data takes a long time to load and to counter that i want to include a loading spinner that shows when the dropdown is clicked and hides after the data has finished loading. So far, i cant get it work. It works when select2 is changed or selected but not when it is clicked. Any suggestions

```
<div class="col-sm-3 loader">
          <%= select_tag 'clone-application-id', options_from_collection_for_select(@applications, :id, :case_code), prompt: "Please Select", class: "form-horizontal single-select" %>
        </div>

 <%= image_tag "ajax-loader.gif", id: "loading-indicator",  style: "display:none" %>
```

my js file

```
$('#clone-application-id').select2().on('change', function() {
    console.log("ok now what");
    $('#loading-indicator').show();
  });
```

Comment: Looks, like you better bind it in ajax.start and ajax.success callbacks

Answer (score 0):

The function is called on select 'changed', but not on 'click'. Is that an expected behavior or just a typo? Maybe changing it to 'click' can solve the situation.

```
$('#clone-application-id').select2().on('click', function() {
  console.log("ok now what");
  $('#loading-indicator').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution on **select2** dropdown loading spinner for **Ajax** calls.. 
With 2 simple functions, we will place the loading icon in the dropdowns

**Add Referances** (select2 dropdown cdn)

```
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

**Html**

```
div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state" id="country">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        <option value="ZB">Zimbamwe</option>
        <option value="TR">Türkiye</option>
    </select>

</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state" id="city"></select>        
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state" id="district"></select>
</div>
```

**addLoadSpiner**

This function use to add or show spinner gif on dropdown. The loading spinner is dynamically created as an html element and added to the dropdown. if already added before, just displayed on screen.

```
  function addLoadSpiner(el) {
        debugger;
        if (el.length > 0) {
            if ($("#img_" + el[0].id).length > 0) {
                $("#img_" + el[0].id).css('display', 'block');
            }               
            else {
                var img = $('<img class="ddloading">');
                img.attr('id', "img_" + el[0].id);
                img.attr('src', 'http://www.lettersmarket.com/uploads/lettersmarket/blog/loaders/common_gray/ajax_loader_gray_512.gif');
                img.css({ 'display': 'block', 'width': '25px', 'height': '25px', 'z-index': '100', 'float': 'right' });
                img.prependTo(el[0].nextElementSibling);
            }
            el.prop("disabled", true);               
        }
    }
```

**hideLoadSpinner**

Add css `css('display', 'none')` is removed from the screen

```
function hideLoadSpinner(el) {
        if (el.length > 0) {
            if ($("#img_" + el[0].id).length > 0) {
                 setTimeout(function () {
                     $("#img_" + el[0].id).css('display', 'none');
                     el.prop("disabled", false);
                }, 500);                    
            }
        }
    }
```

**Load Data With Ajax**

Finally , Loading spinner appears on the display until Ajax has finished

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/GetCities",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                                  'countryId': $("#country option:selected").val()
                                }),
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                var dbSelect = $('#city');

                addLoadSpiner(dbSelect);     

                dbSelect.empty();
                $.each(result, function (index, item) {
                    dbSelect.append("<option value='" + item.id + "'>" + item.text + "</option>")
                });

                hideLoadSpinner(dbSelect);

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError);                  
            }
        });
```